# How to prevent a click event in input field angular code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Whenever I click inside input box. value between + & - symbols is increasing or decreasing. I need to prevent that how can I do that please help

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', [])
.directive('spinner', function() {
return {
restrict: 'EA',
scope: {
jump:'=jump'
},
```

Please see full code from below link
http://plnkr.co/edit/u0LJi8RdVxQIqEPofqWO?p=preview

Comment: As per plunker example Found You need a `+` icon to increment and `-` icon to decrement the values and a text box to jump the values. Please decsribe more the functionality you want for jump.

Comment: only on + & - click should work. eg: please add any value in text & click + or -.  after that click over input box. the value is changing. I need to prevent that click even on input box

Comment: Then do not mouse event on entire directive.  Bind only on those buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below will be the updated code of your app.js..

```
    var app = angular.module('plunker', [])

    .directive('spinner', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
                jump:'=jump'
            },

            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

                scope.spinning = function(action) { 
                      scope.jump = 0;
                        var longpress = 300;                    
                              var start=0;

                    var jumps = document.getElementById("jumps").value;
                    var spinn = document.getElementById("spinn").innerText;

                    var convt = Number(spinn);
                    var jumpconvt = Number(jumps);


                             // jumps text box is null
                         if(jumps === ''){

                             if ( new Date().getTime() >= ( start + longpress )  ) {  
                                 // long press add 2

                                if (action === "add"){

                                   convt= convt + 2;
                                }
                               else {
                                   convt= convt - 2;
                                    }
                              }
                         else{
                         //short press add 1
                            if (action === "add"){

                              convt= convt + 1;
                           }
                          else {
                              convt= convt - 1;
                               }
                         }                               
                       }
                      else{
                             // jumps not null
                         if ( new Date().getTime() >= ( start + longpress )  ) {    
                                 //long press

                            if (action === "add"){

                              convt =  convt + (jumpconvt *2);
                               }

                               else if (action === "sub"){

                                  convt = (jumpconvt *2) - convt;
                               }
                             }

                             else{
                                 // short press

                                 if (action === "add"){

                              convt =  jumpconvt + convt;
                              }

                              else if (action === "sub"){

                                  convt = convt - jumpconvt;
                              }
                             }
                         }                           
                             document.getElementById("spinn").innerHTML = convt;


              };
            },

            templateUrl: 'spinnerDirective.html',               
};
})
```